# jQuery Selectors performance: Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I am building a menu page in which if the user clicks anything that is not a menu link, she/he is taken back to the home page. Here is the page: http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/design/

The div ID wrapper is styled as:

`<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100vh; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; margin: 0 auto; width: 100vw; z-index:-1;" class="hfeed">`

Essentially, the wrapper covers the whole page, and I want the user to be sent back to the home page if she/he clicks on anything that are not the menu links in the center of the page. Here is HTML for the links:

`<header class="header"> 
... stuff ... 
<li class="menu-cloud xlarge"><a href="http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/sample-design-page-2/">Sample Design Page 2</a></li>
... stuff ...
</header>`

The jQuery I wrote is:

```
jQuery(' div#wrapper:not("header") ').click(function() {
    window.location.assign("http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/")
});
```

This code, and many other selector variation attempts, work fine on Firefox and Chrome, but on Safari, anything clicked will take the user back to the home page, including the links which should take you to project pages.

I believe this happens because the wrapper is sized to cover the whole page. The wrapper is fixed position, with z-index -1, and the menu items are relative positioned, z-index 1, to try and put them in front of the wrapper. I believe because of the positioning, the wrapper is always on top because it is fixed positioned. However, even when I relative position the wrapper, and leave its z-index at -1, this does not fix the issue in Safari. So, I am not sure if this is a jQuery or positioning issue in Safari.

Can anyone please advise so that when the menu links are clicked the user does not go to this page:
[Home page](http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a page that might change or disappear, leaving future visitors to be confused.

Comment: The selector you have there, though, is equivalent to `'#wrapper'` because ids must be unique to the document. So the element selector (`div`) is irrelevant, as is the `:not("header")` since either the element with the id will either be a `div`, `header`, or some other element, not both a `div` and a `header`.

Comment: I added some HTML that I think adds sufficient info to the HTML aspects of the question. Yes, you are correct; my method to select a div would not select a header. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery('div#wrapper').click(function(e) {
    if (jQuery(e.target).is(':not("header, header *")'))
       window.location.assign("http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/")
});
```

It would change location if the clicked element is no `header` itself or its descendants.

Comment: I tried what you wrote above, @Kosh Very; I also tried: ` jQuery('div#wrapper:not("header, header ul li a")').click(function() {
    window.location.assign("http://newsite.paulwagenblast.com/")
 });` ; both work in Chrome and Firefox, but they do not work in Safari. I am suspecting it is a CSS positioning issue. I have tried making both elements position:relative, and setting the menu items to z-index 1, and the wrapper to z-index -1 and this doesn't help either.

Comment: This worked; thank you. (A single ) is needed to be added to your second line to close the if condition.)